# Make handlers visible on scene load

Tags: unity

In my dev enviroment I have a couple custom handlers I want to always be visible.

I have already figured out that I can do this by deriving a class from Editor, linking it to the desired component type, and then appending the render method to SceneView.duringSceneGui (in OnEnable(), as the target gameobject information will be available there).

However, this appending now only happens once a specific gameobject carrying the component has been selected. Is there a way I could have the Editor's OnEnable() method properly trigger on opening a scene, for all relevant gameobjects, without manually selecting them first?

Comment: Not sure if this will be helpful but `Awake()` is actually called before `OnEnable()`

Comment: @Jake I think Awake() only exists on MonoBehavior, actually... And I am extending from Editor, not MonoBehavior.